# Semantic UI form input is not sending data to the route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, semantic-ui

The form routes data just fine without the top two inputs included, but I want the blog[make] and blog[model] inputs to be included.

I have deleted various inputs and also used previously created forms. All routes are set up correctly except the first two inputs.

```
<form class="ui form segment"  action="/carBlogs" method="POST">

    <div class="field">
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Make</label>
                <input type="text" name="blog[make]" placeholder="ENTER MAKE">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>MODEL</label>
                <input type="text" name="blog[model]" placeholder="ENTER MODEL">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label>YEAR</label>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="three wide field">
                <input  type="text" name="blog[year]" placeholder="ENTER YEAR">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div h4 class="ui dividing header">
        <p>BLOG</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
            <div class="field">
                <label>TITLE</label>
                <input type="text" name="blog[make]" placeholder="Enter TITLE">
            </div>

            <div class="field">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label">IMAGE</label>
                <input type="text" name="blog[image]" placeholder="Enter IMAGE">
            </div>


    <div class="field">
        <div class="field">
                <label>COMMENT</label>
                <textarea name="blog[body]" placeholder="Enter Blog Here"></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui inverted segment">
        <button type ="submit" class="ui inverted blue button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```